# Command line arguments of R in .Rprofile

Tags: r

First of all, I would like to suppress showing the version info at the start of a new `R` session. It can be done via command line arguments:

> --quiet
>
> --silent
>
> -q

Can it be done via `.Rprofile`?

Comment: Are your new R sessions being run from a terminal, in RStudio, (other)...?

Comment: @duckmayr I use terminal.

Comment: I don't think it's possible from `.Rprofile` based on some experimentation and the limited discussion available from `?.Rprofile`.